# Open other webiste in new tab alogn with my website

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a website-1 ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com)). When a customer reaches out to my website, the other website-2 ([www.example2.com](http://www.example2.com)) should be open in a new tab corresponding with the website ([www.example.com](http://www.example.com)).
How to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do an `<a>` element with the `target="_blank"` attribute.

Like so:

```html
<a href="http://www.example2.com" target="_blank">Example 2</a>
```

If you want them both to load, then you can make it go to the second one in another tab with javascript using the window.onload event.

Like so:

```js
window.onload = function() {
window.open(url, '_blank').focus();
};
```

Comment: If some one type www.example.com in url the website should be open and meanwhile in new table example2.com should also open

Answer (score 1):

I would like to add to Daan Teppema's answer.

Add **rel** property in the tag, if the website is not safe or untrusted add **noopener**. but if you are directing within your website remove the **noreferrer** for SEO tracking purposes.

```
<a href="http://www.example2.com" target="_blank" rel="noreferrer noopener">Example 2</a>
```

This will keep your website tab open and in the meantime open a new tab with the link you've provided.